# How to extract weight values from an output_graph.pb (post transfer learning) in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

It seems I need to use freeze_graph.py (unless I"m mistaken)

'https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py'

This is the graph I want to extract:

```
C:\tmp\output_graph.pb
```

I'm looking at freeze_graph.py but I"m having trouble understanding some of the
arguments of the script AND I'm ending in an import error.

```
--input_graph    = the graph I want to extract.

--input_checkpoint  ? I don't think I need this

--input binary   I don't think I need this as my inputs were image file values


--output_node_names  The labels? 

----input_meta_graph   not sure what this is.
```

I don't see an output argument for a text.file or pickle file that will
hold all weights.

I tried running the following line from command prompt:

```
python3.6 C:\Users\Moondra\tensorflow\tensorflow\python\tools\freeze_graph.py --input-graph=C:\tmp\output_graph.pb
```

However, I'm getting an import error:

```
 from tensorflow.python.tools import saved_model_util
     importError: cannot import name 'saved_model_utils'
```

saved_model_utils seems to be in the same folder, so not sure what the problem is.

Thank you.